# Null values on model after sending model to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using .net MVC.
I have some values in a form like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

On the controller, I get the data like:

```
 public ActionResult NovaPessoa(Person person)
    {
```

The problem is that I just can get values that I have placed the `@Html.TextBoxFor` markup.

All the other complex information, like `person.ContactInformation` is lost after submiting and I can't use the `SaveChanges` in Entity Framework, because it will give me an invalid object after using the `Atach` method.

The question is: Do I need to use the `@Html.TextBoxFor` markup for all my model properties, even if I'm not using then to display anything, just to have them on Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. What people **(incorrectly)** do normally, is use `HiddenFor`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContactInformation)
```

What you should be doing, is cutting down your model into a view model with only the appropriate properties.

So, **don't** use this model:

```
public class PersonVM {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string ContactInformation { get; set; }
}
```

..if all you're doing is updating the contact information. Instead, create a new class for your model:

```
public class PersonContactInfoEditVM {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string ContactInformation { get; set; }
}
```

That's all you need. This saves you from creating invalid objects when you don't add 30 `HiddenFor` elements to your page .. resulting in very broken data.

You might be thinking "ugggghhhh, all that manual mapping from `PersonContactInfoEditVM` to `Person`... I don't want to be writing that sort of code". No one does.. which is why the following libraries exist:

- [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)
- [ValueInjector](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)